# Downstream job is not receiving the build parameters from the upstream job

Tags: jenkins

I'm using ant to generate build parameters in the upstream job and passing them down using "Trigger Parameterized build on other projects". But the downstream job is not receiving them , even though both the builds are Restricted to the same node.

I have other jobs in the pipeline where the build parameter is passing but not when I'm moving from one stage to another.

Sample Output:

```
16:57:35 Running as SYSTEM
16:57:35 Setting version to: #89-NEXT from upstream version
16:57:35 [EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
16:57:35 Building remotely on Slave (wraith acceptance ios-slave integration javascript php7.1) in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/in-release-services
16:57:35 using credential gourav-git
16:57:35  > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
16:57:35 Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
16:57:35  > git config remote.origin.url git@github.com:InterNations/in.git # timeout=10
16:57:35 Cleaning workspace
16:57:35  > git rev-parse --verify HEAD # timeout=10
16:57:35 No valid HEAD. Skipping the resetting
16:57:35  > git clean -fdx # timeout=10
16:57:35 Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:InterNations/in.git
16:57:35  > git --version # timeout=10
16:57:35 using GIT_SSH to set credentials gourav-git-jenkins
16:57:35  > git fetch --no-tags --progress git@github.com:InterNations/in.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
16:57:37  > git rev-parse origin/$GIT_APP_REVISION^{commit} # timeout=10
16:57:37  > git rev-parse $GIT_APP_REVISION^{commit} # timeout=10
16:57:37 ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
16:57:37 ERROR: Build step failed with exception
16:57:37 java.io.IOException: Cannot retrieve Git metadata for the build
```

16:57:37     at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.util.BuildDataHelper.getCommitSHA1(BuildDataHelper.java:87)
   16:57:37     at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.status.sources.BuildDataRevisionShaSource.get(BuildDataRevisionShaSource.java:32)
   16:57:37     at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.status.GitHubCommitStatusSetter.perform(GitHubCommitStatusSetter.java:135)
   16:57:37 Caused: org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.common.CombineErrorHandler$ErrorHandlingException
    16:57:37    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.common.CombineErrorHandler.handle(CombineErrorHandler.java:74)
    16:57:37    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.status.GitHubCommitStatusSetter.perform(GitHubCommitStatusSetter.java:164)
    16:57:37    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:79)
    16:57:37    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    16:57:37    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
    16:57:37    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    16:57:37    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    16:57:37    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    16:57:37    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1841)
    16:57:37    at com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.MultiJobBuild.run(MultiJobBuild.java:76)
    16:57:37    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    16:57:37    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)

Expected Output:

```
Running as SYSTEM
Setting version to: #6558-deploy/2020-03-03 from upstream version
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on docker-ci-040 (database test integration php7.1 guestlist-app) in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/in-release-services
using credential github-internations-jenkins
> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> git config remote.origin.url git@github.com:InterNations/in.git # timeout=10
Cleaning workspace
> git rev-parse --verify HEAD # timeout=10
Resetting working tree
> git reset --hard # timeout=10
> git clean -fdx # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:InterNations/in.git
> git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials GitHub internations-jenkins SSH user
> git fetch --no-tags --progress git@github.com:InterNations/in.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> git rev-parse 54ba1520d2a11276fc3d564c5b5312388abddd10^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 54ba1520d2a11276fc3d564c5b5312388abddd10 (detached)
Enabling Git LFS pull
> git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
> git checkout -f 54ba1520d2a11276fc3d564c5b5312388abddd10
> git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials GitHub internations-jenkins SSH user
> git lfs pull origin
```

Comment: Kindly share sample runs with respective trial way of running things & expected output

Comment: @vinWin - Added the output and expected output.